# How to do the same work multiple times using Dataflow?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud

I have some work that needs to be done repeatedly. For example, let's say I want to roll 2000 dice and collect the result. The caveat is the dice throw depends on `PCollection` How can this be done with Dataflow?

I've tried using a `PCollectionList` but the result is that my Dataflow is too large to start (> 10 MB). Here is an example of what I'd like to do (using `PCollectionList`):

```
// I'd like to operate on things 2000 times. 
PCollection<Thing> things = ...;
List<PCollection<ModifiedThing>> modifiedThingsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
   modifiedThingsList.add(things.apply(ParDo.of(thing -> modify(thing)));
}
PCollection<ModifiedThing> modifiedThings = PCollectionList.of(modifiedThingsList).apply(Flatten.pCollections());
```

Because the JSON representation of the above graph is too large for Dataflow, I need a different way of representing this logic. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the dice throw depends on PCollection"? This is not apparent from your code snippet.

Comment: For instance, let's say `things` was really a `PCollection<Integer>`. An example of "throwing the dice" would be to add a random number to each element in the PCollection, repeating the process 2000 times. I tried to illustrate this via the `modify(thing)` method invocation.

Comment: I'm still confused: ParDo can return an arbitrarily large number of outputs per input. Can you just things.apply(ParDo.of(c -> for (i = 0..2000) c.output(modify(c.element())))) or am I misunderstanding what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParDo` or `FlatMapElements` can return an arbitrarily large number of outputs per input. For example:

```
PCollection<ModifiedThing> modifiedThings = things.apply(
    ParDo.of(new DoFn<Thing, ModifiedThing>() {
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
      c.output(modify(c.element()));
    }
  }
}));
```

Caveat: If you're going to immediately apply other `ParDo`s to `modifiedThings`, [be careful with fusion](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc#preventing-fusion), since 2000 is a pretty high fan-out factor. A good example code snippet for preventing fusion is [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.java#L307).